# INPUT with multiple values of multiple values each

Tags: java, html, servlets

Not sure the best way to do this...

I have an HTML FORM with multiple rows.. But one of the columns also has multiple values.

I know I can receive the `event` into a String array with `getParamaterValues()`. But for the variable `days`, how do I get that into an array of arrays so it's still related to the event column?

It's all coming out of a database so I can't just hard code it.

I'm sure I actually know the answer but my brain is not cooperating... Thanks in advance for the kick-start... I'm using Java servlets. But it's really just an HTML question.

e.g.

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev1">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sat">
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sun">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev2">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Fri">
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sat">
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sun">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev3">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sat">
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Sun">
        <input type="checkbox" name="days" value="Mon">
```

Comment: Don't know about java but in PHP you would add square brackets after the checkbox name to make an array name="days[]"

Comment: @Billy, You don't need that in Java, and it still doesn't help with how to make a 2 dimensional array.

Answer (score 1):

Append the value from the events to the name attribute of the days like ev1_days, ev2_days, ev3_days:

```
<tr>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev1">
  </td>
  <td>
      <input type="checkbox" name="ev1_days" value="Sat">
      <input type="checkbox" name="ev1_days" value="Sun">
  </td>
</tr>
...
...
```

Then you can do something like:

```
String[] events = request.getParamaterValues("event");
for(int i=0; i<events.length; i++)
{
   String[] days = request.getParamaterValues(events[i] + "_days");
   //do something with days....
}
```

You should actually close your td's and tr's by the way.

Comment: That's sort of the hack I did initially. But I was thinking there must be a more elegant way? like an array in each element of the array? i.e. looking for event[0]:ev1 days[0]:[Mon,Tue] etc

Comment: @PrecisionPete, If you build it yourself with something like that, sure. But there's nothing to do it automatically in Java, unless some fancy framework has something.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change name of Checkboxes that belongs to the same event to a unique name.

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev1">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysA" value="Sat">
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysA" value="Sun">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev2">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysB" value="Fri">
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysB" value="Sat">
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysB" value="Sun">
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="event" value="ev3">
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysC" value="Sat">
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysC" value="Sun">
        <input type="checkbox" name="daysC" value="Mon">
```

**Script**

```
    var events = [];
    var daysA = [];
    var daysB = [];
    var daysC = [];
    var jsonData="";

    function c(){
    var eventCB = document.getElementsByName("event");
    var daysACB = document.getElementsByName("daysA");
    var daysBCB = document.getElementsByName("daysB");
    var daysCCB = document.getElementsByName("daysC");

    for(var i=0;i<eventCB.length;++i){
      events.push(eventCB[i].value);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<daysACB.length;++i){
      daysA.push(daysACB[i].value);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<daysBCB.length;++i){
      daysB.push(daysBCB[i].value);
    }

    for(var i=0;i<daysCCB.length;++i){
      daysC.push(daysCCB[i].value);
    }


    jsonData ='{events:['+events.toString()+'],days:[['+daysA.toString()+'],['+daysB.toString()+'],['+daysC.toString()+']]}'

    }
```

*Passing data to Servlet*

```
var jsonComplete = JSON.stringify(jsonData);//You will get below string
//{events:[ev1,ev2,ev3],days:[[Sat,Sun],[Fri,Sat,Sun],[Sat,Sun,Mon]]}
$.ajax({
        url:"URLServlet",
        type:"POST",
        dataType:'json',
        data: {jsonComplete : jsonComplete },
        success:function(data){
            // do whatever required
        },


    });
```

*Receiving Data in Servlet* *Using org.json*

```
JSONObject objJSON = new JSONObject(request.getParameter("jsonComplete "));
JSONArray arrEvents =  objJSON.getJSONArray("events");   
JSONArray arrDays =  objJSON.getJSONArray("days");  

for(int i=0;i<arrEvents.length();++i){
  out.println("event["+i+"]:"+arrEvents.getString(i));//Similar to  event[0]:ev1
}

for(int i=0;i<arrDays.length();++i){
  JSONArray arrDaystemp = arrDays.getJSONArray(i);
    out.println("days["+i+"]:[");
    for(int i=0;i<arrDaystemp.length();++i){
      out.println(arrDaystemp.getString(i));//Similar to days[0]:[Mon,Tue]
    }
    out.println("]");
}
```